# How to use unique health check port on an Application Load Balancer (Container Service) on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, haproxy, amazon-ecs

I have an domain that needs to be routed to both an Application Load Balancer and an EC2-instance depending on the URL path. The Application Load Balancer has a limit of 10 rules per ALB, and I need more.

So to workaround this limit of 10 URLs I would like to setup a request pipeline as follows:

ALB for domain.com -> Docker container with HAProxy with routing rules/reverse proxy -> routes to another ALB or EC2-instance

The setup is fine, I'm having problems with setting up the HAProxy and it's health check. I would like the ALB to health check on a different port rather than the traffic port. In HAProxy I can simply setup multiple frontends, one for the routing (port 80) and one for health check (port 60000). But if I enter port 60000 in the ALBs target group I can't deploy another service due to the dynamic mapping.

Any ideas how to solve this? I rather not expose the health check on port 80 due to it being available for the public net but if that's the only solution it's fine (but how to do it?).

Comment: Please post your config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up with using monitor-uri as the healthcheck, not ideal since it's exposed to port 80 but no secret info is showing there anyway.